# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value sections is a let constant (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I can't find my error with this code

I have this following error message for sections.append(eventMois)

Cannot use mutating member on immutable value sections is a let constant

thanks for your help

```
 class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {

     var sections : [Section]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Receive user defaults which we stored when user logged in

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let firstname = defaults.string(forKey: "usernameValue")
        let lastname = defaults.string(forKey: "nameValue")
        let connect_email = defaults.string(forKey: "emailValue")
        guard let eventMois = defaults.array(forKey: "event_mois") as? [Section] else {return}

        if let sections = sections {
            sections.append(eventMois)
        } else {
            sections = eventMois
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient solution is to declare the array as non-optional empty array

```
var sections = [Section]()
```

Then the entire `if - let` expression is not needed and you can simply write

```
sections.append(eventMois)
```

or

```
sections = eventMois
```

---

Consider that in the expression

```
if let sections = sections {
        sections.append(eventMois)
```

`sections` in the second line is the optional bound local variable and **not** the declared array which causes the error because the local variable is immutable.

Comment: Thanks for your explication, it's very important for me to understand.

I have just taken sections = eventMois

Do you think that I will be able to put my array eventmois in sections as eventmois comes from mysql.

thanks for your answer

Comment: If `defaults.array(forKey: "event_mois") as? [Section]` succeeds `sections = eventMois` is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't have any more errors, but my view shows empty sections.
I will probably verify the creation of the array.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot cast an object from `UserDefaults` directly to a custom class. You have to make `Section` adopt  `NSCoding` and use `NS(Key)Archiver`

Comment: I have recuperated a php array that I've coded in json.
Then, I've recuperated this array and I've put it (defaults.set(event_mois, forKey: "event_mois")) and finally I wanted to use it.
So I think I don't have to do it this way?
Have you got an example or a procedure to realize this action?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can only save and read property list compliant types (`NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSData` and `NSDictionary / NSArray` containing the 4 types) to `UserDefaults`. if you are able to write `event_mois` to `UserDefaults` you have to read the same type

Comment: I worked well last night. I have redone all the script and I recover directly on the page in Json which comes from PHP and everything works thanks again

Answer (score 1):

***This is your issue***

```
if let sections = sections {
            sections.append(eventMois)
        } else {
            sections = eventMois
        }
```

inside this if let `sections` is inmutable as the **error message says**, you need a simple if != nil check

**replace by this**

```
if sections != nil {
            sections.append(eventMois)
        } else {
            sections = eventMois
        }
```

or a **guard**  like this

```
  guard sections != nil else{
         sections = eventMois
         return
     }
  sections.append(eventMois)
```

Hope this helps